# Media Query Not Working?

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

Trying to apply a bit of Media Query.

CSS without media query

```
blockquote {
margin: 1.5em 0;
font-family: 'Gentium Basic', Georgia, serif;
font-size: 20px;
line-height: 1.6em;
font-weight: normal;
font-style: italic;
border-left: 1px dotted;
padding: 0 0 0 25px;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -150px;
width: 650px;
}
```

Then applied:

```
/* larger than 800px */
@media only screen and (min-width: 801px) {
  #mobileNav {
    height: 0 !important;
  }
}
/* 800px and smaller */
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  #bannerImage {
    background-attachment: scroll !important;
  }

blockquote {
margin: 1.5em 0;
font-family: 'Gentium Basic', Georgia, serif;
font-size: 20px;
line-height: 1.6em;
font-weight: normal;
font-style: italic;
border-left: 1px dotted;
padding: 0 0 0 25px;
}
```

Site [here](https://michael-thomason-9irq.squarespace.com/journal)

What I'm trying to do is have the blockquote fit onto the screen. Currently it does this when the width of the page is changed:

[image]

When I want it to do this:

[image]

Comment: Can you define *Not working?*

Comment: What do you want your media query to do?

Comment: Yes, now that's some sportsman spirit. You shouldn't delete the questions you ask. People help you here, you shouldn't run away after you get your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not defining the `width` in the media query, it will just use the `width` defined in the general stylesheet(which in this case, it's `650px`), so you need to define `width` again in the media query rule block.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    blockquote {
       margin: 1.5em 0;
       font-family: 'Gentium Basic', Georgia, serif;
       font-size: 20px;
       line-height: 1.6em;
       font-weight: normal;
       font-style: italic;
       border-left: 1px dotted;
       padding: 0 0 0 25px;
       width: 100%; /* Specify some width here */
       /* You should use auto value as you are using margins and paddings */
    }

    /* Other styles goes here */
}
```

> Note: If you have only styles in your media query which you've pasted
>   here, than I would like to inform you that you are not closing the
>   media query block.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/aCSKX/)

Comment: @Michael Shared the demo, resize the fiddle window